# Создание копий сайта на Wordpress с кастомным url под нужным языком и регионом

Tags: seo

Я в вордпрессе и пхп ещё новичок.
`https://al-arabia-intr.com/`
Сделал вот такой мультиязычный сайт.
Перевод сделан через плагин Polylang, и соответственно под каждый язык в админке свой контент.
Яыковые версии доступны с таким урлом:
`https://al-arabia-intr.com/` - основная (на русском)
И так далее через слэш /en, /ar, /uk для англ, арабского и укр языков
Затем этот сайт передали Сео-спецу, и он говорит, что нужно прописать ещё
теги с хрефлангами и языковыми версиями под отдельные страны.
Сеошник говорит, что нужно вот так:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://al-arabia-intr.com/ar-ua/" hreflang="ar-ua">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://al-arabia-intr.com/ar-ly/" hreflang="ar-ly">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://al-arabia-intr.com/uk-ua/" hreflang="uk-ua">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://al-arabia-intr.com/ru-ua/" hreflang="ru-ua">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://al-arabia-intr.com/en-ly/" hreflang="en-ly">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://al-arabia-intr.com/en-ua/" hreflang="en-ua">
```

То есть в урлах проставить en-ua, en-ly и тд под нужные страны нужные языковые версии

Вот с этим я и встрял, поскольку Полилэнг автоматом добавил в урлы языковые приставки, а xml карту сайта автоматом добавляет плагин YoastSEO
Соответственно если я перейду, допустим, по адресу `https://al-arabia-intr.com/en-ua/` , то будет редирект 404

В этом и сложность, не могу понять, как решить этот вопрос, чтобы при переходах на урлы с вставками en-ua, en-ly и тд открывалась нужная языковая версия, а не переход на 404.
И как создать копию сайта так, чтоб при открытии, допустим, `https://al-arabia-intr.com/en-ua/` открывалась страница с контентом на английском, то есть `https://al-arabia-intr.com/en`, но в урле было `https://al-arabia-intr.com/en-ua/`
И так под другие языковые версии

Answer (score 0):

> То есть в урлах проставить en-ua, en-ly и тд под нужные страны нужные
> языковые версии

Нужно поменять сеошника на грамотного. Важно только значение `hreflang`, а что в урле - совершенно не важно. Может быть любая абракадабра.

Матчасть: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?hl=ru

Comment: Как объяснить это сеошнику, если он мне скинул эту же статью, и при этом говорит, что урлы должны быть как `hreflang`

Comment: @rt_kit  раскройте глаза вместе с сеошником. Там нет требований к урлам. Более того - там ест совершенно чёткие примеры, с абсолютно одинаковыми названиями файлов для разных языков. Есть и ссылки на генераторы и тестирование.

Comment: Я то это понимаю, видео по ссылке посмотрел, но для меня с ним это как на другом языке говорить, и как ещё аргументировать, ибо не разбираюсь настолько хорошо. Он приводит в пример сайт, где есть локальные подстройки под регион типо /en-ca 
Но у меня на сайте нет контента даже, который подставляется под конкретный регион, только языки разные

Comment: Не кино смотреть надо, а читать. Там всё предельно ясно написано. И примеры даны.